# PowerBuilder unsupported argument type in Oracle remote procedure

Tags: oracle, powerbuilder, procedure, database

help me please. I have stored procedure

```
 message
 (
 out_error OUT INTEGER, 
 client_absid IN INTEGER,
 document_subject IN VARCHAR, 
 document_text IN VARCHAR, 
 document_attachedfiles IN FILEINF_T,
 p_client_abs IN VARCHAR  
)

FILEINF_T AS OBJECT (
attachedfiles_name VARCHAR(255)
, attachedfiles_val BLOB      
)
```

I use local external function for call it

```
 SUBROUTINE message ( ref long out_error, long client_absid, 
  string document_subject,string document_text, readonly fileinf_t 
  document_attachedfiles[], string client_abs) RPCFUNC ALIAS FOR "message"
```

Structure:

```
 global type fileinf_t from structure
  string        attachedfiles_name
  blob      attachedfiles_val
 end type
```

In script:

```
FILEINF_T files[]
FILEINF_T file
file.attachedfiles_name = "test"
files[1] = file
....
this.message ( ref ll_return, pclient_absid, pdocument_subject, 
pdocument_text,  files, pclient_abs)
```

I give error "Unsupported argument type in DLL function message at line 23 in function uf_ib_messagefile of object ub_ib6_transaction."

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to answer from "PowerBuilder" http://scn.sap.com/thread/3265959

Answer (score 0):

Your stored proc declaration doesn't show document_attachedfiles to be an array. Either pass in a single instance of the structure or update the stored procedure signature to accept an array.

Comment: I tried to removed [ ] from the RPC definition, but error is.